# node, grunt custom task using stream

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, task

Hi can anyone help me with a custom grunt task?

I'm basically using child_process to call

```
var cp = exec(cmd, {}, function (err, stdout, stderr) {}
```

this of course has the stdout etc.  If I

```
cp.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

it rights a bunch of stuff to the console.  I am making this call in a loop so here's a skeleton

```
this.files.forEach(function(f) {
      var src = f.src.map(function(filepath) {
      var cmd = util.format("%s %s", options.xUnit, src);
      var cp = exec(cmd, {}, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      ....
      cb();
 });
 if (options.stdout || grunt.option('verbose')) {
     cp.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
 }
```

This all works fine.  but since I'm doing it several times I want at the very least to be able to index how many times stderr has a value.  I'm basically running collections of tests.  If all pass then stderr is blank if not, I don't want to stop the rest of the tests I want them all to run, but i'd like to output at the end "you have 3 collections that have failing tests".  I don't see why I can't seem to get it to work.  If I declare

```
var output = 0;
```

then

```
if (options.stderr || grunt.option('verbose')) {
     cp.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
     output ++;
}
```

I then try to print to console after they all run but it's always 0.

I would really like to some how get a copy of ALL the output and parse out the last line from each test session which has the number of tests that failed in it.  But that just seems way out of realm of possiblity. I've tried all manner of stuff with the streams and got less than nothing.

Anyway, if anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it